# How to use jovial_svg with assets

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, assets

I was using `jovial_svg` library for fetching svg from internet because my svg files looks corrupted with `flutter_svg` library.
Now I want to use `jovial_svg` library for my files which are in my `assets` folder.

I tried

```
ScalableImageSource.fromSvg()
```

but i didn't make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
ScalableImageWidget.fromSISource(
      si: ScalableImageSource.fromSvg(
        MySVG(imagePath: image.svg),
        'key',
        compact: true,
      ),
    ),

class MySVG extends AssetBundle {
  final String imagePath;
  MySVG({required this.imagePath});
  @override
  Future<ByteData> load(String key) async {
    // TODO: implement load
    return await rootBundle.load(imagePath);
  }

  @override
  Future<T> loadStructuredData<T>(
      String key, Future<T> Function(String value) parser) {
    // TODO: implement loadStructuredData
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More context is needed.  Maybe if you posted the relevant part(s) of your source?  It's good practice to boil it down to a simple example.  Are you getting any error messages or warnings when you run your program?

Take a look at https://github.com/zathras/jovial_svg/blob/main/example/lib/main.dart for a minimal example.  And, of course, make sure the assets are included in your program, you have the right path, etc.

Comment: In this minimal example it is fetching data from internet. But I want to use this library for my asset files

Comment: Yes.  So you should modify it, using the method that takes the SVG file from an asset.  Or, if you want to test rendering first, put your files somewhere you can load them by http.